# how to list in a descending order by time, xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to list by using XSLT all recipes described in an XML document, and this list has to contain the recipes in a descending order by the preparation time. Recipes having the same preparation time have to be listed in descending order by the cooking time. I don't know how to do the last part, i'm not even sure about the first one. Here is what I have until now:

```
<recipes>
    <recipe>
        <lunch>
            <preparationTime>00:10</preparationTime>
            <cookingTime>00:30</cookingTime>
            <ingredients>
                <ing1>Honey</ing1>
                <ing2>Avocado</ing2>
                <ing3>Chicken breast</ing3>
                <ing4>Tomatoes</ing4>
            </ingredients>
            <preparationSteps>
                <step1>Proin consectetur ligula eget magna placerat luctus</step1>
                <step2>Donec eu sem at justo imperdiet tempor</step2>
                <step3>Curabitur vitae ipsum rutrum, facilisis velit tincidunt, rhoncus turpis</step3>
                <step4>Etiam maximus malesuada feugiat</step4>
            </preparationSteps>
        </lunch>
    </recipe> 

    <recipe>
        <desert>
            <preparationTime>00:23</preparationTime>
            <cookingTime>01:00</cookingTime>
            <ingredients>
                <ing1>Kiwi</ing1>
                <ing2>Avocado</ing2>
                <ing3>Apple</ing3>
                <ing4>Honey</ing4>
            </ingredients>
            <preparationSteps>
                <step1>Proin consectetur ligula eget magna placerat luctus</step1>
                <step2>Praesent volutpat orci non nunc eleifend tincidunt</step2>
                <step3>Morbi at est ac ligula ornare condimentum</step3>
                <step4>Jaher maximus malesuada feugiat</step4>
            </preparationSteps>
        </desert>
    </recipe>

    <recipe>
        <diet>
            <preparationTime>00:07</preparationTime>
            <cookingTime>00:00</cookingTime>
            <ingredients>
                <ing1>Water</ing1>
                <ing2>Lemon</ing2>
                <ing3>Apple</ing3>
                <ing4>Tomato</ing4>
            </ingredients>
            <preparationSteps>
                <step1>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostras</step1>
                <step2> Quisque id pretium eros</step2>
                <step3>Pellentesque elit velit, feugiat vel rhoncus</step3>
                <step4>Vee milori malesuada feugiat</step4>
            </preparationSteps>
        </diet>
    </recipe>

    <recipe>
        <dinner>
            <preparationTime>00:18</preparationTime>
            <cookingTime>00:11</cookingTime>
            <ingredients>
                <ing1>Fish</ing1>
                <ing2>Lemon</ing2>
                <ing3>Honey</ing3>
                <ing4>Salt</ing4>
            </ingredients>
            <preparationSteps>
                <step1>Donec eu sem at justo imperdiet tempor</step1>
                <step2>Nurcas non tellus eu magna dictum hendrerit</step2>
                <step3>Morbi at est ac ligula ornare condimentum</step3>
                <step4>Derbis maximus malesuada feugiat</step4>
            </preparationSteps>
        </dinner>
    </recipe> 

</recipes>
```

and the xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Recipes</h2>
        <xsl:for-each select="recipes/recipe">
        <ul>
            <li><xsl:value-of select="lunch"></li>
                <li><xsl:value-of select="preparationTime"></li>
                <li><xsl:value-of select="cookingTime"></li>
                <ul><xsl:value-of select="ingredients">
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="ing1"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="ing2"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="ing3"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="ing4"></li>
                </ul>
                <ol><xsl:value-of select="preparationSteps">
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="step1"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="step2"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="step3"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="step4"></li>
                </ol>


            <li><xsl:value-of select="desert"></li>
                <li><xsl:value-of select="preparationTime"></li>
                <li><xsl:value-of select="cookingTime"></li>
                <ul><xsl:value-of select="ingredients">
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="ing1"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="ing2"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="ing3"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="ing4"></li>
                </ul>
                <ol><xsl:value-of select="preparationSteps">
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="step1"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="step2"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="step3"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="step4"></li>
                </ol>


            <li><xsl:value-of select="diet"></li>
                <li><xsl:value-of select="preparationTime"></li>
                <li><xsl:value-of select="cookingTime"></li>
                <ul><xsl:value-of select="ingredients">
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="ing1"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="ing2"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="ing3"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="ing4"></li>
                </ul>
                <ol><xsl:value-of select="preparationSteps">
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="step1"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="step2"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="step3"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="step4"></li>
                </ol>


            <li><xsl:value-of select="dinner"></li>
                <li><xsl:value-of select="preparationTime"></li>
                <li><xsl:value-of select="cookingTime"></li>
                <ul><xsl:value-of select="ingredients">
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="ing1"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="ing2"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="ing3"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="ing4"></li>
                </ul>
                <ol><xsl:value-of select="preparationSteps">
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="step1"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="step2"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="step3"></li>
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="step4"></li>
                </ol>
        </ul>

        <!--
        <xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(NoteEnteredOn), ,' '),':') mod 12" 
          order="descending" data-type="number" /> 
        <xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(NoteEnteredOn),':'), ' ')" 
          order="descending" data-type="number" /> -->
    </body>
</html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you want to first group `recipe` elements by `preparationTime` then in XSLT 2.0 you can do that easily using e.g. `<for-each-group select="//recipe" group-by=".//preparationTime"><xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" order="descending"/>...</xsl:for-each-group>`. If you need to use an XSLT 1.0 processor then you can use Muenchian grouping http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Your *times* are perfect sortable as "string". Therefor for sorting you only need to add following xslt:sort to your `for-each`:

```
      <xsl:sort select="*/preparationTime"  order="descending"  /> 
      <xsl:sort select="*/cookingTime"  order="descending"  />
```

But there are some other issues with your xslt:

- Your xslt is not valid.
- In each recipe is only one entry of lunch, desert , etc. But you try to select all of them for each recipe.

The `for-each` may look as the following:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="recipes/recipe">
      <xsl:sort select="*/preparationTime"  order="descending"  /> 
      <xsl:sort select="*/cookingTime"  order="descending"  /> 
    <ul>
        <li><xsl:value-of select="name(*)"/></li>
        <li><xsl:value-of select="*/preparationTime"/></li>
        <li><xsl:value-of select="*/cookingTime"/></li>

        <!-- some more infos    -->
    </ul>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I wrote the code below, which looks great, and added the ingredients + preparationSteps, but it doesn't do what it should. I'm getting something like: "00:10 00:30 Honey Avocado Chicken breast Tomatoes  Proin consectetur ligula eget magna placerat luctus Donec eu sem at justo imperdiet tempor Curabitur vitae ipsum rutrum, facilisis velit tincidunt, rhoncus turpis Etiam maximus malesuada feugiat    00:23 01:00 Kiwi Avocado Apple Honey  Proin consectetur ligula ... " why doesn't it look like a list?

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="preparationSteps"/>`adds all text context from `preparationSteps` and all children.  Try `<li><xsl:value-of select="preparationSteps/step1"></li>`